Small effect size with large sample yields significant result, how to understand
1.I can't understand how a small effect can produce a significant result with a large sample? I find it much clearer when I use code instead of abstract formulas.
I created two arrays samples and samplesC(experimental values).
A truncated normal distribution was used to generate normal distributions.
These values ​​are plotted in the upper graph. In the lower graph, n values ​​are randomly selected from these values, N is the number of times. Values ​​are plotted along the x-axis and probabilities along the y-axis. The power and size of the effect are displayed on the screen. N, n can be changed and the graph will be dynamically redrawn.
If I choose N=1 and increase n, I don't see the power getting any bigger.
2.All the examples I found on the internet, when calculating power, have an experimental (red) distribution on the right. Can there be an experimental distribution on the left and how is power calculated then?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from scipy.stats import norm, truncnorm

N = 1000
mu, sigma = 80, 21
lower, upper = 30, 120
muC, sigmaC = 84, 21
lowerC, upperC = lower + 3, upper + 3

samples = np.sort(truncnorm.rvs(
        (lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=N, random_state=0))
samplesC = np.sort(truncnorm.rvs(
          (lowerC-muC)/sigmaC,(upperC-muC)/sigmaC,loc=muC,scale=sigmaC,size=N, random_state=0))

pdf = norm.pdf(samples, np.mean(samples), np.std(samples))
pdfC = norm.pdf(samplesC, np.mean(samplesC), np.std(samplesC))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

ax[0].plot(samples, pdf, lw=2, color="blue", label="H0")
ax[0].plot(samplesC, pdfC, lw=2, color="red", label="H1")
ax[0].legend()

ax_N = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
ax_n = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03])
s_N = Slider(ax_N, "N", valmin=1, valmax=300,valinit=1, valstep=1)
s_n = Slider(ax_n, "n", valmin=1, valmax=300,valinit=25, valstep=1)

def update(val):
    N = s_N.val
    n = s_n.val
    generation = np.sort(np.array([np.random.choice(samples, n) for _ in range(N)]).ravel())
    generationC = np.sort(np.array([np.random.choice(samplesC, n) for _ in range(N)]).ravel())
    mu_samples, mu_samplesC = np.mean(generation), np.mean(generationC)
    std_samples, std_samplesC = np.std(generation), np.std(generationC)
    pdf = norm.pdf(generation, mu_samples, std_samples)
    pdfC = norm.pdf(generationC, mu_samplesC, std_samplesC)

    interval = norm.interval(confidence=0.95, loc=mu_samples, scale=std_samples)
    cdf = norm.cdf(interval[1], mu_samplesC, std_samplesC)
    x, y = mu_samples, (np.max(pdf) + np.min(pdf)) / 2

    effect_size = (abs(mu_samples - mu_samplesC) /
                          np.sqrt((std_samples ** 2 + std_samplesC ** 2) / 2))

    ax[1].clear()
    ax[1].plot(generation, pdf, lw=2, color="blue", label="H0")
    ax[1].plot(generationC, pdfC, lw=2, color="red", label="H1")
    ax[1].axvline(x=interval[1], linestyle="--", color="red")
    ax[1].text(x, y, "power =" + str(round(1 - cdf, 4)) +
            "\n" + "Cohen's d =" + str(round(effect_size, 4)), fontsize=12)

s_n.on_changed(update)
s_N.on_changed(update)
update(0)


plt.show()

Update 03.11.2024
Thanks to Demetri Pananos and jginestet. Here's what got (can see how the confidence interval narrows dynamically).
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import t
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

alpha=0.05

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

ax_n = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
s_n = Slider(ax_n, "N", valmin=4, valmax=150,valinit=3, valstep=1)

sample = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
mu, std = np.mean(sample), np.std(sample)


def update(val):
    N = s_n.val
    #tstat = t.ppf(1 - alpha / 2.0, df=N - 1)# tstat and interval[1] identical
    df = N - 1
    interval = t.interval(0.95, df=df)
    width_of_ci = interval[1] * std / np.sqrt(N)
    pdf = t.pdf(sample, df)

    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(sample, pdf, lw=2, color="red")
    ax.axvline(x=mu - width_of_ci, linestyle="--", color="blue")
    ax.axvline(x=mu + width_of_ci, linestyle="--", color="blue")

s_n.on_changed(update)
update(0)

plt.show()



I can't understand how a small effect can produce a significant result with a large sample?

In short, this is because large samples offer us precise enough estimates to state that the parameter being estimated is statistically different from the null.
Take the sample mean as an example, and suppose we conduct a statistical test to determine if the sample mean is different from 0.  We can do this with a t-test.
The conclusion from the t-test (significant or not) will be equivalent to the determining if the Wald confidence contains 0 or not.  The Wald confidence interval looks like
$$ \bar{x} + t_{n-1,1-\alpha/2} \dfrac{\widehat{s}}{\sqrt{n}} $$
Where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean and $\widehat{s} / \sqrt{n}$ is the standard error of the estimate of the sample mean. So long as the population from which you sample has a mean different from zero, then $\bar{x} \rightarrow \mu$ by the Law of Large Numbers, and the width of the confidence interval shrinks inversely proportional to $\sqrt{n}$.  Quadruple your sample size and the confidence interval is half as long.
So then how do large samples yield significant results?  Large samples result in very narrow confidence intervals, which are unlikely to contain 0 if the true mean is non-zero, which would be equivalent to a significant result.
Since you find these concepts easier with code, consider the following simulation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, t
from tqdm import tqdm


def sim(n, scale=1, alpha=0.05):
    sample = norm(scale=scale).rvs(n)
    tstat = t.ppf(1 - alpha / 2.0, df=n - 1)
    width_of_ci = 2 * tstat * np.std(sample) / np.sqrt(n)

    return width_of_ci


def avg_width_of_ci(n, nsims=10, alpha=0.05):
    widths = [sim(n, alpha=alpha) for _ in range(nsims)]

    return np.mean(widths)


def true_width(n, scale=1.0, alpha=0.05):
    # True in the limit of large samples
    return 2 * norm.ppf(1 - alpha / 2.0) * scale / np.sqrt(n)


def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=120)

    n = np.arange(10, 1000, 5)
    avg_widths = np.zeros_like(n, dtype=float)

    for i, k in tqdm(enumerate(n)):
        avg_widths[i] = avg_width_of_ci(k)

    ax.plot(n, avg_widths, label="Empirical")
    ax.plot(n, true_width(n), color="red", label="Theoretical", linestyle="dashed")
    ax.set_xlabel("N")
    ax.set_ylabel("Avg Width of CI")
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()




We can actually calculate the probability that the confidence interval excludes 0, which leads to the concept of statistical power.  Generally, large samples lead to more statistical power, which means we are more likely to see a significant result (under certain assumptions).

I would like to clarify one point.  A large sample with a small effect size gives a p-value < 0.05, but the power is also small, which does not allow rejecting the 0 hypothesis? This is a kind of warning.

May be nit-picking, but your answer says "we can do this with a t-test", but the Wald CI formula used is for a z-test (not even, as you use s, not $\sigma$). You may want to tidy this up, in an otherwise straight on answer.

@jginestet Oh, yea I suppose since we might be dealing with small samples then the difference is salient.  Let me tidy up

@inquirer If power is small, then the "large" sample is not large enough.  "Large" needs some sort of reference point -- and if you are concerned with rejection of the null when it is false (and under certain assumptions about the truth), then statistical power is the correct reference point.

@DemetriPananos @ jginestet I started studying statistics not so long ago. I got stuck on understanding power. In my understanding, the greater the difference between the averages and the smaller the standard deviations, the greater the power. And I tried changing the sample size, with an increase the p-value becomes less than 0.05 but the power changes little. If I set N = 1000 for my top graph, then p-value < 0.05, and if N = 100, then p-value > 0.05. I'll try to reread everything again and rethink it.

@inquirer, the power of a test goes up as the difference goes up, as the standard deviation goes down, and as the sample size goes up. And all 3 should make intuitive sense: the bigger the difference, the easier it will be to detect the difference, the smaller the variability the easier again it will be to detect the difference, and the larger the sample size, the easier again (because there will be less uncertainty about our estimates of mean and sd).
